# Django Displaying Each User's Profile

Tags: django, django-views, django-users

I am building a website where there is a table at the homepage, and in that table there are people's names, numbers, their categories, the city they reside in, etc.

I would like to create a link, that when a visitor clicks on any of the users' name, the visitor gets directed to that specific user's profile page. Right now, my code works partially. When I click any user, I get redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/7/. That user ID number of "7" is the logged in user's ID. So no matter which user I click on, I get redirected to the profile page of the logged in user.

Also, when I log out of the current user I am logged in to, I get this error message: "NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'profile_pk' with keyword arguments '{'pk': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P[0-9]+)/$']"

Here is what I have done with my code so far:

views.py

```
def ustaprofil(request, pk=None):
        if pk:
            user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        else:
            user = request.user
        args = {'user': user}
        return render(request, 'user.html', args)

def ustalist(request): #view that renders the table
    usta = Usta.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'usta': usta})
```

urls.py

```
path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.ustaprofil, name='profile_pk'),
```

models.py

```
class Usta(models.Model):
    user =  models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gizlilik_sozlesmesi = models.BooleanField("Gizlilik Sozlesmesini Okudum Onayliyorum*" , null=True)
    sartlar_sozlesmesi = models.BooleanField("Sartlar ve Kosullar Sozlesmesini Okudum Onayliyorum*", null=True)
    isim = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    kategori = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    eposta = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    aciklama = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    il = models.ForeignKey(Il, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ilce = models.ForeignKey(Ilce, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    resim = models.ImageField(default='ananas.jpg',
                              upload_to='profile_images')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.isim
```

home.html (where the link to each user's profile is in)

```
<script>
  function LinkFormatter(value, row, index) {
  return "<a href='{% url 'profile_pk' pk=user.pk %}'>"+value+"</a>";
}
</script>

    <tr>
          
          <th data-formatter="LinkFormatter" data-field="isim" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Isim</th>
          <th data-formatter="LinkFormatter" data-field="kategori" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Kategori</th>
          <th data-formatter="LinkFormatter" data-field="il" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Il</th>
          <th data-formatter="LinkFormatter" data-field="ilce" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Ilce</th>
          <th data-formatter="LinkFormatter" data-field="telefon" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Telefon</th>
          <th data-formatter="LinkFormatter" data-field="profil"><a href="profile/">Profili Gor</a></th>
        </tr>
```

Finally, user.html (users' profile page template):

```
{% block content %}
<div class="row my-4">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-info text-white">
                Usta Profil Sayfasi
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="row p-3">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <table class="table table-borderless">
                        <thead>
                            <span class="h4">{{ user.username }} profili</span class="h4">
                                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-right" href="{% url 'user-profile-update' %}">Duzenle</a>
                            <hr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ user.usta.resim.url }}" alt="profile-image">
                            </div>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Kullanici Ismi</th>
                                <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Firma veya Usta Adi</th>
                                <td>{{ user.usta.isim }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Kategori</th>
                                <td>{{ user.usta.kategori }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Website</th>
                                <td>{{ user.usta.website }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">E-Posta</th>
                                <td>{{ user.usta.eposta }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Phone</th>
                                <td>{{ user.usta.telefon }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Aciklama</th>
                                <td>{{ user.usta.aciklama }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Il</th>
                                <td>{{ user.usta.il }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Ilce</th>
                                <td>{{ user.usta.ilce }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

So I have 2 specific questions:

1. How do I make my code open each user's profile page according to their ID's. [http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/7/'s](http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/7/%27s) profile when I click on user number 7's link to their profile, and [http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/8/'s](http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/8/%27s) profile when I click on user number 8's link to their profile.
2. How do I solve that "NoReverseMatch" error? I believe the error is because I am not logged in to any user, it cannot display any links to any logged in user profile, since I am not logged in to any user.

Comment: Where is the view that shall render the tanle?

Comment: Just added the view that renders the table on views.py section. I put a comment saying #the view that renders the table for easy find

Answer (score 0):

You can’t mix JS execution With Django Templates and the template won’t execute JS Code. The linkformatter will always return same value as user.pk is request.user.pk

Here an example template

```
 <table>
  {% for user in usta%}
   <tr>
    <td><a href=‘{%url ‘profile_pk’ user.id%}’> {{user.username}}</a>
    </td></tr>

{%endfor%}
</table>
```

Comment: It gives this error when I click on the user links: No User matches the given query.

Comment: Try this `<a href=‘{%url ‘profile_pk’ user.pk %}’> {{user.username}}</a>`

Comment: It is only opening the profile of the current logged in user, no matter which user I click on. I really appreciate the help by the way, you rock! Hopefully I will get great at coding too and help others like you are!

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing user PK to the template.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Just watch Dennis Ivy's video on creating dynamics URL's. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhjnQIpXqPc&list=PL-51WBLyFTg2vW-_6XBoUpE7vpmoR3ztO&index=9

The videos are in 2 parts, make sure to watch both of them. Everything seemed so complicated until I Dennis explained it! It was so simple!